# Is it really not required to generate salts for bcrypt?

Tags: go, cryptography, passwords, bcrypt

I'm using the golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt package for storing passwords. Looking at documentation and other SO questions, it seems like I'm not supposed to (or at least don't *have* to) generate a salt for the password before I generate the hash. This seems counter to everything that I've read about cryptography and modern password storing, and makes me a bit nervous. Is it really secure enough to just pass the user's normal password into `bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword`, or am I reading things wrong?

Comment: Does the output change if you execute the same command with the same password? If so, then there is already salt generation included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bcrypt package [generates the salt](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/b8a0f4bb4040f8d884435cff35b9691e362cf00c/bcrypt/bcrypt.go#L143-L147) for the application.  The return value from [GenerateFromPassword](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt#GenerateFromPassword) encodes the cost, salt and hash of the password.